# awk and printf in bash

Tags: bash, awk, printf

I am trying to get the rounded number of the average load in the past 5 mins. So here goes my command:

```
 uptime | awk -F, '{print $5}'|printf "%.0f\n"
```

It seems incorrect as it always give me 0.

If I tried to use a variable as intermediate between awk and printf, then it is correct

```
 avgload=$(uptime | awk -F, '{print $5}')

 printf "%.0f\n" $avgload
```

So anything wrong with my first try?

Thanks and regards!

UPDATE:

Just for getting the average load in the past 5 mins, here is the output of uptime on my linux server (Kubuntu)

`$ uptime

                                                                                                   13:52:19 up 29 days, 18 min, 15 users,  load average: 10.02, 10.04, 9.58`

On my laptop (Ubuntu) it is similar

`$ uptime

13:53:58 up 3 days, 12:02,  8 users,  load average: 0.29, 0.48, 0.60   `

That's why I take the 5th field.

Comment: Note that the problem is because printf doesn't accept parameter input this way.  You'll need to use xargs or backticks as noted in various solutions below.

Comment: Nope, just use `awk` to do the formatting. It has `printf` built in.

Comment: So uptime |awk -F, '{printf "%0.f\n",$5}' then.

Comment: You're welcome.  Please select one of the answers as the answer, to mark this question complete.

Comment: It's probably better to take `$(NF-1)` rather than $5, because that date and time information is formatted differently for shorter uptimes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The 5th comma-separated field from the uptime output is non-existant (on my system at least), which is why you keep getting zero.  The 5-minute uptime is the second-to-last field, so this works:

```
uptime | awk '{printf "%.0f\n",$(NF-1)}'
```

Comment: +1 for using `awk` to do the formatting rather than piping its output unnecessarily to another command.

Comment: Thanks! (1) what does $(NF-1) mean for awk? (2) The 5th comma-separated field is the 5-minute uptime on my systems.See my update to OP. What is yours like?

Answer (score 3):

Simplest version (use built-in awk printf - kudos [Dennis Williamson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26428/dennis-williamson)):

```
uptime |awk -F, '{printf "%0.f\n",$5}'
```

Original answer: Run it through xargs instead.

```
uptime |awk -F, '{print $5}' |xargs printf "%0.f\n"
```

Comment: So, what exactly does `xargs` buy you here? Presumably the output of `uptime` is a single line.

Comment: xargs tacks the output from awk onto the end of the command line.  So you get 'printf "%0.f\n" 0.75', if the output from awk was 0.75.

Comment: I know what `xargs` does, but I forgot that printf doesn't accept stdin!

Answer (score 1):

You can just do

```
printf "%.0f\n" `uptime | awk -F, '{print $5}'`
```

The backticks are essentially command substitution, so whatever the output of `uptime | awk -F, '{print $5}'` is, will be the argument to `printf`.

The problem with the first approach is that printf just does not accept arguments from `stdin`; if it *did* take arguments from `stdin`, then it would have worked fine.  Also, no arguments to printf apparently does mean "put zero in for my arguments".

```
$ echo hello | printf "%s"

$ printf "%s" hello
hello
$ printf "%.0f"
0
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can feed the input to printf on stdin.  Try this version:

```
printf "%.0f\n" `uptime | awk -F, '{print $5}'`
```

Comment: Oops... 9 seconds too slow.  :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have /proc mounted you can use /proc/loadavg:

```
LANG=C
read _ uptime _ </proc/loadavg
printf "%.0f\n" $uptime
```

The above code uses only built-in shell commands. However, 
if you like, you can use awk too:

```
 awk '{printf "%.0f\n",$2}' /proc/loadavg
```